# True or False? Not testing data is needed for CART if there is not future prediction

Tags: r, machine-learning, cart

I am analysing a data set with a relatively a small sample size. For the nature of my data, it is considered already quite large, but for its statistical power it is just in the lower limit. I sampled a population and I am just interested in knowing what characteristics define the individuals.

I am using CARTs and GLMEMs to analyse the data. I am quite new to machine learning techniques, but as far as I can understand I could use 100% of my data set for a "training" CART model if I do not have a future prediction to make from my data. I do not need to test with pseudo-R2, right?

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the reason that test data are set aside. It is not done for "future prediction" but rather to ensure that the model is not over-fitting the training data / give reasonable estimates out performance. If you have a relatively small sample size I would suggest bootstrapping your original sample instead of having hold-out test data.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, now I undertand better small sample sizes and data partitioning. I have Breiman and Friedman (1984) book named CART. So, as far as I undertand I should do some cross-validation, ideally with v=10. But, since my model has a numerical independent variable I could not do it. So, I calculated the pseudo-r2 proposed by McFadden as a likelyhood method for model standards (fit). Is that it for a CART? Having a good pseudo-r2 value is enough to validate my model?

Comment: What are *GLMEMs*? A typo? Can you check/explain?